# wordpress pinboard theme

Tags: posts, themes, widgets, content

I would like to add content(just plain text) to the first page of my site and also have the posts displayed on it aswell. I am using pinboard theme.

Does anyone know a good way of achieving this without having to hack away on the code?

BR

Kimpo

Answer (score 1):

You can place custom-CSS in /Theme Options/Layout/Custom CSS
This will not mix up with the original CSs then and also survive theme updates.
This way is not very comfortable, but at least relatively clean.

Answer (score 0):

To insert plain text before the posts and after the navigation bar, use a text-widget (design -> widgets) and place it in the "boxes" area. Or in the sidebar or anywhere you want.